# Student Seeking Beginning Calculus Advice

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, self-learning, advice

I am a junior in high school and I am seeking advice on where I should begin learning calculus. I have just completed trigonometry as a school class, and I have to admit I enjoyed it. During the course, I consistently felt that learning trigonometry through school was too slow, and it made me want to start learning mathematics on my own. I am fascinated with math, and I want to begin learning higher-level mathematics as soon as possible. As you can probably see, I am a complete beginner when it comes to knowing about the different calculus classes. I do not know the difference between any of the different calculus classes and I am simply seeking guidance as to which one I should begin first.

I would appreciate any advice you can give me.

Thank you for your time.

Note: This question is not limited to calculus advice. I am merely looking for guidance on the next step I should take in my mathematical career. If that means combinatorics, abstract algebra or something else that is unrelated to calculus, I completely welcome that as well. I have just been told that calculus is the most reasonable next step.

Comment: Several recommendations: MIT open courseware and Khan Academy are awesome. The Stewart calculus book is very well-written. Some students disagree, but I think it's because they don't understand that all technical math is hard to learn. There are tons of helpful pictures and so many problems. You can buy the solutions manuals and learn by example.

Answer (score 2):

Calculus is *not necessarily* the most reasonable next step.  I don't advise self-study in calculus, because there are so many subtleties that aren't obvious to a student.

Find a good book and read it, and do as many of the problems as you can.  One of my favorite books for general math, accessible from many levels, is [*Mathematics: A Human Endeavor*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Mathematics_A_Human_Endeavor.html?id=zO4ApMb3B8QC) by Harold R. Jacobs.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew, I'll be sure to check it out. What do you think about studying on an online site like Khan Academy, but supplementing that education with a book or two?

Comment: I still feel like there's no rush to calculus.  There's plenty of time to learn that with the guidance of a good professor.

Answer (score 1):

First... I *LOVED* calculus in high-school, did quite well, especially as it was so very useful in physics, my main subject.

That being said, and after having been a professor of mathematics and physics and statistics, my strong recommendation to students of all interests is to take *STATISTICS* before calculus.  It is so important in daily life and science.  Just look at the news today.

Comment: Thanks, David, I have always been fascinated with physics. If I take statistics first, in your opinion, what order should I take the calculus classes following statistics?

Comment: Statistics first, then single-variable calculus.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what kind of background you have etc. But I think a great first place to start learning calculus is Khan academy (I mean as a literal first introduction). This was my first introduction to calculus, and I remember a lot of the ideas being clearly conveyed. Just watch all(/as many as you can) of his videos on derivatives and integrals. I remember spending about 3 weeks/a month on derivatives (basic definitions, power law, sum, product, quotient, chain rule, derivatives of trig functions, exponential, log etc), and spending an equal amount of time on integrals.

Once you get a baseline understanding for what these ideas are supposed to represent, I think reading any calculus textbook will be much more palatable. It doesn't really matter too much what the first book you use is (considering you're only a junior in High school); just pick one which is semi-understandable, and **SOLVE AS MANY PROBLEMS AS YOU CAN**. By the way, a lot of single-variable calculus is very intimately connected with basic Classical Mechanics. So, if you have an interest in physics as well, I suggest you learn the two topics side by side (kinematics and dynamics using calculus etc).

---

Aside from calculus, the subject which I'm finding most useful is linear algebra; it really is the foundation to a lot of more advanced math. As you learn more calculus, you'll realize that the whole idea is to understand a non-linear problem by understanding a simpler, linear problem. So, pretty much by "definition", linear algebra is a must if you want to pursue any further calculus.

Comment: You know, that is funny, because I have heard many people in the math and scientific communities say that linear algebra makes calculus much simpler to understand. I even picked up a book about a year ago, on linear algebra, but I had trouble with some of the terms, because the book relied on the reader having an already-existing calculus  foundation. Thanks for the advice! Ill be sure to revisit it.

Comment: @K2SO I can see why you might think so, and I think I would agree with you somewhat. The issue (it is an issue if you're really interested in pursuing higher level math) with the way calculus is taught nowadays is that it is primarily computational-focused. So much so that student's don't even know/appreciate what the fundamental concept behind all of calculus is: "approximation by linear things"(I didn't fully appreciate this idea till I took multivariable calc). This is partially understandable because linear algebra in one-dimension is pretty trivial; there's nothing much to be said really.

Comment: So, for one-dimensional calculus, the full force of abstract linear algebra will only make things more complicated. However, if you eventually plan on doing more math, then you'll end up taking a course on multivariable calculus at some point. Then, the concepts are so much more easily stated and understood using the concepts of linear algebra. Really, every major theorem in (multivariable) calculus, like implicit function theorem, change of variables for integration etc are all proven first in the linear case, and then reducing the general case to linear case by a sequence of approximations.

Comment: Yes, that makes complete sense. I really hate how everything is based on required standardised curriculum as opposed to in-depth exploration into the topic. I was looking at some of the exercises on the Khan Academy's precalculus corse and, (although I just took a glance) it seemed like all of the topics were revisited from concepts I have already learned. What are your thoughts on skipping precalculus altogether, and do you think I will regret it later on?

Comment: @K2SO Honestly I don't know what exactly is in a "precalculus" course, because my schooling was simply grade1-12 lol. But as long as you think you're familiar with basic algebra, quadratic equations, factoring cubic polynomials, trigonometric functions, the various identities (like double angle formulae, half angle), solving equations and graphing trig/other functions etc all these kinds of things, then I think you're ready for (an introduction to) limits and calculus. Just start watching  a bunch of videos on calculus, and if you think you don't understand something, just learn it as you go.

Comment: I agree with that learning philosophy, and I think that is a great way to approach mathematics in general. Thank you again for all of the helpful advice. Just a a side question, however; I am curious, what is your background, and how did you get into mathematics?

Comment: @K2SO I've always been interested in math and physics, so I guess it was only natural for me to continue studying it (I'm still an undergrad).

Answer (score 0):

Starting with limits and basic single variable calculus provides a strong foundation for thinking more abstractly about functions and the relationships between them. While it can be complex, a site like Khan Academy is a good place to start getting used to the basic concepts in calculus, especially if you're studying on your own. 
From there, you'll be ready to explore more widely and to discover what other fields catch your interest - the advantage of starting with single variable calculus is that it starts to teach you some of the notation, proof methods, and analytical tools that other fields assume you'll already know.

Comment: That is excellent advice. Thank you.